# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'slides'

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, typeerror, prettyphoto

I got this problem when I add this following script in my header.php file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                    $("#logo a span").css("opacity","0");
                    $("#logo a span").hover(function () {
                        $(this).stop().animate({
                            opacity: 1
                        }, 'slow');
                    },
                    function() {
                        // animate opacity to nill
                        $(this).stop().animate({
                            opacity: 0
                        }, 'slow');
                    });
                });
    </script>
```

And before "/head" I add this code

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

When I open the page, it couldn't load the slide, and there was some error in my general.js.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'prettyPhoto'
$.fn.superfish.sfgeneral.js:92
f.Callbacks.njquery.js:2
f.Callbacks.o.fireWithjquery.js:2
e.extend.readyjquery.js:2
c.addEventListener.B

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'slides'
$.fn.superfish.sfgeneral.js:45
f.event.dispatchjquery.js:3
f.event.add.h.handle.i
```

There is also a jquery.js in my web directory, but these errors description above are in that file.

I have searched the problem for a couple of days, but I still don't get the solution. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't reference the `prettyPhoto`jQuery plugin.

`prettyPhoto` isn't a function in the jQuery core functions, you need to use the "library" that extends jQuery with that function.

You should add the reference to the plugin right **after** the jQuery core library:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="{prettyPhoto location}"></script>
```

BTW, the code that throws the error isn't in the code you pasted here...

Comment: but if I don't write that (my first code above) additional script in my header.php, all scripts (prettyPhoto,etc) can work fine... the problem show, when I add that script... please give me more explanations.. thnks

Comment: @AnjarTriyoko. I don't know it doesn't make sense. Paste all of your code in http://jsFiddle.net and let me check it out. anyway it's not those lines and you need to add a reference to the plugin.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Actually this problem showed because of my lack of knowledge of jQuery&friends..:D. The problem has been solved just by removing the addition script reference in my header.php... once again, thanks..